# Page url is damaged when changing language back to the default language

Tags: joomla-3.x, multilingual

My site is running on Joomla3.

When I load my page for first time everything is fine (the default language is Spanish) -- even if I navigate in menus.

However, when I click the English flag and I navigate with the menus then I return to the Spanish language, it doesn't load anything -- everything looks white, the URL looks like this `https://mywebsite.com`, the `www.` is removed and it also contains the `/es` something like this `https://mywebsite/es`.

I don't know what to do. I know it's not the update because I when I test locally, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off caching in global config. It seems to be not updating your files.

I have checked this on my own site and I ended up with /en/ behind the domain name and it was persistent. Then I held <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> and clicked refresh.

Also turn off all language modules and plugins.

Comment: Hi, I don't have the caching on

Answer (score 0):

Do you see an error message if you activate [error reporting](https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla/how-to-turn-your-error-reporting-to-maximum/)?

Maybe you can also check again that you have set everything up correctly: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Setup_a_Multilingual_Site